# SHA1 PHP encryption versus SHA1 Python encryption

Tags: php, python, django, encryption, sha1

For a project I am currently working on we are attempting to migrate an old PHP/MySQL server to a new, Django/PostgreSQL server.  On the PHP server we are currently managing passwords by taking a string, sha1()ing it and then comparing it to the database.  I know [python has a sha1() function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sha.html), but I do not enough about cryptography to know if these functions vary in implementation and how the PHP version compares to the Django one.  Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an aside, you probably [don't want to be using SHA1 to hash passwords at all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking#Prevention).

Comment: Yeah I realize that now that I have done more research... But converting from sha1 to some other hashing system when you already have users seems like a whole additional issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's and Python's SHA1 implementations should definitely give the same result.

See for yourself:

```
$ python
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha1("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog").hexdigest()
'2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12'
>>> exit()

$ php -a
php > echo SHA1("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate the testing.  I should have done that myself.

Answer (score 2):

`sha1` in PHP accepts an optional second argument ($raw_output; default value 
false). In Python there are two separate methods to handle that: `hexdigest` and `digest`.

## Case 1

For `$raw_output` set to `false` we use `hexdigest`.

In PHP:

```
sha1("My string");
```

In Python:

```
from hashlib import sha1
sha1("My string").hexdigest()
```

## Case 2

For `$raw_output` set to `true` we use `digest()`

In PHP:

```
sha1("My string", true);
```

In Python:

```
sha1("My string").digest()
```